# can we have foreign keys on a column having json datat type in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I want to set the data type of one of the field of a table as JSON and make it as a foreign key to another table.is it possible in MySQL now as of version 5.7.8.

Comment: have you tried creating it as a foreign key

Answer (score 0):

I found this :

> Note that JSON columns cannot have a default value, be used as a primary key, be referenced as a foreign key or have an index. You can create secondary indexes on generated virtual columns, but it’s possibly easier to retain an indexed value in a separate field.

(https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/)

So no you can't and by the way it's strongly recommanded to use simple field as key like 'int' for example.